# Button onclick and save cookie on Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 local website, that has an article and a popup on the first page that leads to that article. In that article I also have a button and I want when the button is clicked by a user, the website to "remember" the user and not show the popup again. I thought I could change the text of the button and store it as a cookie.
This is the code for the button:

```
<button id="test" value="test" onclick="Press()">Press Here</button>
<script>
function Press() {
    var test= document.getElementById("test");
    test.innerHTML="Thank you";
    document.cookie = "Inner"= + test.value +"; expires=Fri, 5 Aug 2016 01:00:00 UTC;";}
</script>
```

And this is the code of the external js file that handles the popup:

```
      function openColorBox(){

if (document.cookie.length != 0){
   var buttonvaluearray = document.cookie.split("=");
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = buttonvaluearray[1];
}

if (test.innerHTML != "Thank you"){
        document.getElementById("popup").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.onclick= function(){
        document.getElementById("popup").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
}
    setTimeout(openColorBox, 5000);
```

But when I load the page, the popup shows as usual, but the text of the button changes immediately from "Press here" to "0; Drupal.toolbar.collapsed". I am a new web developer so I am sure something is wrong with the code I used either for the cookie creation/testing or  the if statement of the external javascript file, but I can't spot the mistake(s). Any suggestions or opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case closed!
All I had to do is to use localStorage from JavaScript, at the first script, and test it afterwards at the external js file in order to create the popup!

Comment: I had a similar situation where I couldn't get a change in the cookie or session to persist in a drupal page to hide a footer, and localStorage did the trick: `localStorage.setItem("hideFooter", 1);`. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trick is here..

Rather than storing value at client side , please store it in server side and run the check on each page.

Comment: And how is this done? You mean by using php? I want to edit this specific article so I change it's html code. That's why I try JavaScript

Comment: No, no, please do not go by java script. It`s not the best practice at all. Yes, you need to use PHP session to store the values.

Comment: I can't use php code at the html of the article though, right? Then, I have to change the template.php file or something else? And, is there an example of how I can do this? My PHP knowledge is not that great you see.

Comment: You need to find out the function which is rendering HTML template, so in that function you need to put session.

Comment: I want this to be on this specific article only. I guess it is possible,right? Also, do you have an online example of this function? As I said before, I am not that good at PHP

Comment: And how should I make the session onclick of the button? Doesn't that require JavaScript?

Comment: You need to use AJAX for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I found a JavaScript way though, that fits my knowledge better. The local storage is more convenient for me. I will upvote you for your assistance, because I have posted the same question 3 times with different ways and nobody answered any of my questions